# Injecting a prototype bean into a singleton bean

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring and trying to understand the concept "**Injecting a prototype bean into a singleton bean**". As per my understanding **In singleton, only a single instance per Spring IoC container, no matter how many time you retrieve it**. `validator.validate(requestId);`, because still `private RequestValidator validator` not instantiated. 
I developed below example where in a singleton bean I give a reference of prototype bean like below:

```
<bean id="requestProcessor" class="com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor">
        <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
</bean>

<bean id="validator" class="com.injection.testing.RequestValidator" scope="prototype" />
```

**RequestProcessor.java**

```
public class RequestProcessor {
    private RequestValidator validator;

    public RequestProcessor(){
        System.out.println("Constructor:: RequestProcessor instance created!");
    }

    public void handleRequest(String requestId){
        System.out.println("Request ID : "+ requestId);
        validator.validate(requestId);
    }

    public RequestValidator getValidator() {
        return validator;
    }

    public void setValidator(RequestValidator validator) {
        this.validator= validator;
    }
}
```

**RequestValidator.java**

```
public class RequestValidator {
    private List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<String>();

    public RequestValidator() {
        System.out.println("Constructor:: RequestValidator instance created!");
    }

    // Validates the request and populates error messages
    public void validate(String requestId){
        System.out.println("RequestValidator :"+requestId);
    }

    public List<String> getErrorMessages() {
        return errorMessages;
    }
}
```

Now when I called the main method I see the following output:
**MainDemo.java**

```
public class MainDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        RequestProcessor processor = (RequestProcessor) context.getBean("requestProcessor");
        processor.handleRequest("1212");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        processor.handleRequest("1213");
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
Constructor:: RequestProcessor instance created!
Constructor:: RequestValidator instance created!
Request ID : 1212
RequestValidator :1212
------------------------
Request ID : 1213
RequestValidator :1213
```

Now looking at the output, it looks like for the 2nd call `processor.handleRequest("1213");` bean is not instantiated, instead already instantiated bean gets used thats why constructor wont get called again. So Prototype bean `validator` acting as a singleton bean only.

**To me :** it is expected that when ever I fetch requestProcessor from application context, it will be wired with a `new validator` as we declared the validator bean is of prototype scope. But this does not happen.

How to solve it ? Is my understanding correct ?

Another way:

```
<!-- Lookup way  -->
    <bean id="requestProcessor" class="com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor" >
        <lookup-method name="getValidator" bean="validator" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator" class="com.injection.testing.RequestValidator" scope="prototype" />
```

If I call my main method I see below **output + error**: Here code `validator.validate(requestId);` executes, `private RequestValidator validator;` is not instatiated and whats why null pointer exception coming.

I've shown in the below code:

```
public class MainDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        RequestValidator requestValidator = (RequestValidator) context.getBean("validator");

        RequestProcessor processor = (RequestProcessor) context.getBean("requestProcessor");
        processor.handleRequest("1212");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        processor.handleRequest("1213");
    }
}
```

Now I see the below error:

```
Constructor:: RequestProcessor instance created!
Constructor:: RequestValidator instance created!
Request ID : 1212
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:12)
    at com.injection.testing.MainDemo.main(MainDemo.java:14)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Injection happens only once, when the Spring context is started. If bean has `prototype` scope, Spring will create new prototype bean for every injection. But prototype bean will not be created every time you call its methods. Lets consider next example:

```
<bean id="firstRequestProcessor" class="com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor">
        <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
</bean>

<bean id="secondRequestProcessor" class="com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor">
        <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
</bean>


<bean id="validator" class="com.injection.testing.RequestValidator" scope="prototype" />
```

In this case both of `RequestProcessor` beans will have its own instance of `RequestValidator` bean.

---

Lookup method is the method, you should call every time when you need new instance of prototype bean. It's better to make this method `abstract`, because anyway Spring will override this method automatically. For example:

```
public class abstract RequestProcessor {

    public void handleRequest(String requestId){
        System.out.println("Request ID : "+ requestId);
        RequestValidator validator = createValidator(); //here Spring will create new instance of prototype bean
        validator.validate(requestId);
    }

    protected abstract RequestValidator createValidator();
}
```

Note, that `createValidator` returns instance of `RequestValidator` and has not any parameters. Also you don't need private class variable `validator`. In this case bean's configuration will looks like:

```
<bean id="requestProcessor" class="com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor" >
    <lookup-method name="createValidator" bean="validator" />
</bean>

<bean id="validator" class="com.injection.testing.RequestValidator" scope="prototype" />
```

Now every time you call `createValidator` method, Spring will create new instance of `validator` bean.

You can find more details in [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection).

Comment: Thank you. Now I understood the concept at least, but I dont see your code is working. Its yielding error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor.createValidator()Lcom/injection/testing/RequestValidator;
 at com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:12)
 at com.injection.testing.MainDemo.main(MainDemo.java:13)  `

Comment: I created separate thread for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460585/lookup-method-injecting-a-prototype-bean-into-a-singleton-bean-issue. Please reply here.

Comment: @user4567570 You have to use abstract method `createValidator` as lookup method. Not `getValidator`.

Answer (score 0):

When spring creates the context, it will instantiate an instance of the RequestProcessor.  During the instantiation of that instance, an instance of the RequestValidator is created and injected in the RequestProcessor.

Because any subsequent reference to the RequestProcessor Bean will access the same instance of the RequestProcessor in the context - and it is already fully constructed - there will never be a call to create a new instance of a RequestValidator.  Although your Validator is scoped to be a prototype - in the example above - you only ever ask for a single copy - when you create the RequestProcessor singleton.

For the second part of your question - you misunderstand the use of the lookup-method.  Spring allows you to override the method on your RequestProcessor - so when you call requestProcessor.getValidator() - spring will return a new instance of that RequestValidator.  However - during the construction of your requestProcessor instance - you never initialized the validator field.  Nor did spring inject a validator during instantiation.  Hence the NullPointerException.

Comment: So it mean Prototype scope of RequestValidator will not be prototype. It will be singleton. Right ? Could you answer on lookup method also, I dont see its working fine

Comment: No - the scope of the RequestValidator is prototype.  Which means that every time you request an instance of the RequestValidator Bean - you will get a unique instance.  In your example above - you only requested a single instance - in your RequestProcessor Bean.  If you created another Bean definition - say RequestBlahBean - and injected a RequestValidator - that would be a second instance of the RequestValidator Bean - unique from the one injected in your RequestProcessor singleton.

Comment: Do confirm - Since `requestProcessor` is `Singleton` and `validator` is `prototype`, so when Spring will create new prototype bean for every injection (which will be once since `requestProcessor` is `Singleton`). But prototype bean will not be created every time you call its methods. Right ? How to solve error of 2nd query ?

Comment: Confirmed.  Ken's example illustrates the solution to your 2nd query.  The AbstractMethodError comes from a name mismatch between the bean definition e.g. "...lookup-method getValidator..." and the name of the abstract method e.g. createValidator()

Comment: Many thanks. Does Scoped Proxies is also the way to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

> **Lookup method injection**
>
> As noted earlier, lookup method injection is an advanced feature that
>   you should use rarely. It is useful in cases where a singleton-scoped
>   bean has a dependency on a prototype-scoped bean. Using Java for this
>   type of configuration provides a natural means for implementing this
>   pattern.

```
public abstract class CommandManager {
    public Object process(Object commandState) {
        // grab a new instance of the appropriate Command interface
        Command command = createCommand();

        // set the state on the (hopefully brand new) Command instance
        command.setState(commandState);
    return command.execute();
    }

    // okay... but where is the implementation of this method?
    protected abstract Command createCommand();
}
```

> Using Java-configuration support , you can create a subclass of
>   CommandManager where the abstract createCommand() method is overridden
>   in such a way that it looks up a new (prototype) command object:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public AsyncCommand asyncCommand() {
    AsyncCommand command = new AsyncCommand();
    // inject dependencies here as required
    return command;
}

@Bean
public CommandManager commandManager() {
    // return new anonymous implementation of CommandManager with command() overridden
    // to return a new prototype Command object
    return new CommandManager() {
        protected Command createCommand() {
            return asyncCommand();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In most application scenarios, most beans in the container are singletons. When a singleton bean needs to collaborate with another singleton bean or a non-singleton bean needs to collaborate with another non-singleton bean, you typically handle the dependency by defining one bean as a property of the other. A problem arises when the bean lifecycles are different. Suppose singleton bean A needs to use non-singleton (prototype) bean B, perhaps on each method invocation on A. The container creates the singleton bean A only once, and thus only gets one opportunity to set the properties. The container cannot provide bean A with a new instance of bean B every time one is needed.

A solution is to forego some inversion of control. You can make bean A aware of the container by implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface, and by making a getBean("B") call to the container ask for (a typically new) bean B instance every time bean A needs it.

With this approach , our business logic is get coupled with Spring conatiner (Application Context) which does not looks to be a good Solution. An alternate of this is **Lookup Method Injection**.