# lookup method - Injecting a prototype bean into a singleton bean issue

Tags: spring

I am developing code for the `Injecting a prototype bean into a singleton bean` code, so far I developed code like below and when I run the main method, I see the below error is coming.

```
Jan 04, 2017 2:59:41 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6ed322: startup date [Wed Jan 04 14:59:41 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 04, 2017 2:59:41 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Constructor:: RequestProcessor instance created!
Constructor:: RequestProcessor instance created!
Request ID : 1212
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor.createValidator()Lcom/injection/testing/RequestValidator;
    at com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:12)
    at com.injection.testing.MainDemo.main(MainDemo.java:13)
```

**spring.xml**

```
<!-- Lookup way  -->
    <bean id="requestProcessor" class="com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor" >
        <lookup-method name="getValidator" bean="validator" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator" class="com.injection.testing.RequestValidator" scope="prototype" />
```

**RequestProcessor.java**

```
public abstract class RequestProcessor {
    private RequestValidator validator;

    public RequestProcessor(){
        System.out.println("Constructor:: RequestProcessor instance created!");
    }

    public void handleRequest(String requestId){
        System.out.println("Request ID : "+ requestId);
        RequestValidator validator = createValidator(); //here Spring will create new instance of prototype bean
        validator.validate(requestId);
    }

    public RequestValidator getValidator() {
        return validator;
    }

    public void setValidator(RequestValidator validator) {
        this.validator= validator;
    }

    protected abstract RequestValidator createValidator();
}
```

**RequestValidator.java**

```
public class RequestValidator {
    private List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<String>();

    public RequestValidator() {
        System.out.println("Constructor:: RequestValidator instance created!");
    }

    // Validates the request and populates error messages
    public void validate(String requestId){
        System.out.println("RequestValidator :"+requestId);
    }

    public List<String> getErrorMessages() {
        return errorMessages;
    }
}
```

**MainDemo.java**

```
public class MainDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        //RequestValidator requestValidator = (RequestValidator) context.getBean("validator");

        RequestProcessor processor = (RequestProcessor) context.getBean("requestProcessor");
        processor.handleRequest("1212");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        processor.handleRequest("1213");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: The config looks OK, most probably there is a missing CGLIB library try adding it to classpath

Comment: Its already present in classpath. Added pom.xml above also. Please guide now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update  your `spring.xml` to shown below

```
<bean id="requestProcessor" class="com.injection.testing.RequestProcessor">
    <lookup-method name="createValidator" bean="validator" />
</bean>
```

Basically you need to specify the name of the `abstract` method name in `lookup-method` xml attribute.

I got below output after the corrected configuration

> Jan 04, 2017 4:11:20 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>   INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@13c675d: startup date [Wed Jan 04 16:11:20 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   Jan 04, 2017 4:11:20 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   
> INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
>   
> Constructor:: RequestProcessor instance created!
>   
> Request ID : 1212
>   
> Constructor:: RequestValidator instance created!
>   
> RequestValidator :1212
>   
> Request ID : 1213
>   
> Constructor:: RequestValidator instance created!
>   
> RequestValidator :1213